# Setting hostname for Spark executors in Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I need to **configure hostname for the Spark executor launched from Mesos coarse grained mode**. By default IP is showing for the host name.

Spark UI to verify the executor hostname
[image: 1]

> In stand alone , I was able to solve this issue by setting the
> SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME  - environment variable in each worker node. But in Mesos I am stuck.

I tried configuring following options , but did not worked

1. setting  spark.executorEnv.SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME in the spark session ( Spark conf)
2. Setting SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME in the sparkEnv.sh located in the spark tarball which is specified in the spark executor uri during deployment

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am doing this to achieve datalocality with other frameworks like Hadoop , Alluxio etc..

Refer : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10149

I dont find any solution for Mesos anywhere :(